# Normalizing 16 bit int values to 0-1 floating points

Tags: python, tensorflow, floating-point

I normalize an 16 bit image with int values from 0 to 65535 to a range from 0 to 1 with float values.
Now my question: Is the dtype = float16 enough or is float32 necessary, to have a good accuracy later if I normalize the image back to 0-65535?

Thanks in advance!

best regards

Answer (score 0):

`float16` is insufficient for a quality mapping for a 16 bit image mapping as clearly not all values can be exactly encoded as `float16`.  The largest `float16` is [65504](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding).  Information is lost and round tripping is not possible for all values.

`float32` is sufficient for a quality for 16 bit image mapping as it has 24 significand bits and a sign bit.  All 16 bit values can be exactly encoded as a `flt32`.

*32 bit* to `float32` [0.0... 1.0] to *32 bit*  mapping may still fail to round trip.  It depends on how the mapping was done.  As OP did not post the mapping code, we can hope, but not verify.

Comment: Since there are more values in the 0 - 65535 16bit float range than in the 0 - 1 16bit float range, the possible input values would need to be limited, or accept fidelity loss.

Comment: @Andrew True.   0 - 65535 values that have more than 11 leading significant bits set lose info in the conversion to float16.